# python: What does the "+" mean in the slicing object?

Tags: python

As I read the [mayavi mesh example](http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/mlab_helper_functions.html#mayavi.mlab.mesh), I don't know what the "+" means in the slicing object.

```
...
pi=numpy.pi
dphi, dtheta=pi/250.0, pi/250.0
[phi, theta]=numpy.mgrid[0:pi+dphi*1.5:dphi,0:2*pi+dtheta*1.5:dtheta]
...
```

What does this kind of slicing mean? I would understand if it is in this format:

```
numpy.mgrid[0:pi:dphi,0:2*pi:dtheta]
```

Comment: `[0:pi+dphi*1.5:dphi,0:2*pi+dtheta*1.5:dtheta]` is the same as `a = pi+dphi*1.5; b = 2*pi+dtheta*1.5; [0:a:dphi,0:b:dtheta]`

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic#Addition_.28.2B.29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just the numerical addition...

```
a[x:y+z:w]
```

is the same as

```
a[x : (y+z) : w]
```